# Spring MVC MySQL Access denied / Unable to obtain JDBC Connection

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSVfImmM03c) to have a connection with my MySQL 5.7 on Windows 10 and developing on STS 3.9.4. On the tutorial everything is smooth but I cannot establish a connection. I am decided to learn Spring MVC first before Spring Boot, so I want to build my app only with Spring MVC. I tried changing my connector, MySQL dialect, the host address, I accessed the DB through command line (pasting credentials to avoid typos), clean project in STS, update Maven project. I cannot make it work. I tried also with external MySQL DB, I contacted the administrators. No success. I think I am missing/mismatching something but I can't figure out. Help please!

My database.properties file:

```
database.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
database.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
database.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/<DB name>?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false
database.username=tisho
database.password=no_pass
```

My servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.examples.tisho" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />                          

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">        
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>     
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>         

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password" />
    </bean>            

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.examples.tisho.model.Book</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${database.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>        
</beans>
```

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.examples.tisho</groupId>
  <artifactId>Nice_project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <springframework.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</springframework.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>    
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>    
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>      
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

STS console output

```
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Infoleven_Library' did not find a matching property.
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.8
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Apr 27 2018 19:32:00 UTC
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         9.0.8.0
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_144
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Tihomir\Workspace_STS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.8
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Tihomir\Workspace_STS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.8
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Tihomir\Workspace_STS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.8\endorsed
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_144/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_144/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_144/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\ANDROID_SDK\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\curl-7.57.0\src\;C:\Tihomir\VVVAMP\bin\php\php7.1.9;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Tihomir\VVVAMP\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.19\bin;C:\Users\E5430\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\E5430\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\E5430\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Tihomir\eclipse_spring-tool-suite-3.9.4\sts-bundle\sts-3.9.4.RELEASE;;.]
May 24, 2018 12:45:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
May 24, 2018 12:45:37 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
May 24, 2018 12:45:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
May 24, 2018 12:45:37 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
May 24, 2018 12:45:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 921 ms
May 24, 2018 12:45:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
May 24, 2018 12:45:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.8
May 24, 2018 12:45:41 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
May 24, 2018 12:45:47 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
May 24, 2018 12:45:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
May 24, 2018 12:45:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
May 24, 2018 12:45:47 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
May 24, 2018 12:45:47 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu May 24 12:45:47 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
May 24, 2018 12:45:47 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
May 24, 2018 12:45:48 PM org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from class path resource [database.properties]
May 24, 2018 12:45:48 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFO: Mapped "{[/books/addBook],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.examples.tisho.controller.BookController.addBook(com.examples.tisho.model.Book,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
May 24, 2018 12:45:48 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFO: Mapped "{[/books],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.examples.tisho.controller.BookController.listBooks(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
May 24, 2018 12:45:48 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFO: Mapped "{[/books/addBook],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.examples.tisho.controller.BookController.addBookForm(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
May 24, 2018 12:45:48 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFO: Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.examples.tisho.controller.HomeController.home(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
May 24, 2018 12:45:48 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
May 24, 2018 12:45:49 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu May 24 12:45:47 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
May 24, 2018 12:45:49 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu May 24 12:45:47 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
May 24, 2018 12:45:49 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
May 24, 2018 12:45:49 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
May 24, 2018 12:45:49 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
May 24, 2018 12:45:49 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
May 24, 2018 12:45:49 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
May 24, 2018 12:45:50 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Access denied for user 'tisho'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
May 24, 2018 12:45:50 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
May 24, 2018 12:45:50 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl makeLobCreatorBuilder
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
May 24, 2018 12:45:51 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
May 24, 2018 12:45:51 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:971)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4813)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5125)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.getConnection(AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTable(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.getTableInformation(ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.performMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:511)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'tisho'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:127)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:862)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:444)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:226)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:196)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.getConnection(AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.java:43)
    ... 66 more
```

I try to configure everything in XML, rather than using classes. So, I didn't provide any Java class. If you need it, please tell me.

I don't exclude that the problem is on the DB side but I don't know what it can be..

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, But I am not able to add.

Where is your database name?

Hibernate need a database to connect. Verify Your Properties file like this:
https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples/blob/master/spring-boot-mysql-springdatajpa-hibernate/src/main/resources/application.properties

More Information: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: Thank you! I knew I had to add the DB name but this was from my last desperate trial when I tried without the DB name. I have specified the DB name in the URL, I updated my question.

Comment: Seen that I am new to Spring, I wanted to learn Spring MVC before Boot and I was trying to build my app only in Spring MVC. The documentation guidelines speak only about Spring Boot way. Also you suggest Spring Boot solutions. So your suggestion is to go with Spring Boot??